# Ionic iOS Build Error

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to build this Ionic 1.x project in iOS using XCode 8 and iOS10. I have installed everything correctly and 
reinstalled the platform and plugins several times. I keep getting the following error display when I build the app. This is 
the first time I have ever seen this error and Google searches have turned up empty. Does anybody have any insight or possible 
solutions for this?

```
Ld /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.app/DATINGAPP normal x86_64
    cd /Users/ryanminor/Code/golf-ionic/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.2.sdk -L/Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DATINGAPP.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=10.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DATINGAPP_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/DATINGAPP.app.xcent /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a -weak_framework ImageIO -framework CoreLocation -framework AVFoundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DATINGAPP_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.app/DATINGAPP

duplicate symbol _kCDVAssetsLibraryPrefix in:
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVCapture.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVCapture.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVAssetsLibraryPrefix in:
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFile.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFile.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVAssetsLibraryPrefix in:
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVLocalFilesystem.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVLocalFilesystem.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVAssetsLibraryPrefix in:
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.o
duplicate symbol _kCDVFilesystemURLPrefix in:
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVFileTransfer.o
    /Users/ryanminor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DATINGAPP-bpfxnegwyinbazfokzwmcdqoeqic/Build/Intermediates/DATINGAPP.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DATINGAPP.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CDVAssetLibraryFilesystem.o
ld: 8 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

UPDATE

Here are two screenshots of the compile sources are and also the linker flags area. I removed the Obj-C linker flags and rebuilt but it still failed with the same error as above.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try looking into your project Build Phases and under the compile sources. I had a similar issue where there were files included in my compile resources twice for some reason. Also check if there are any linker flags like -ObjC in your Other Linker flags section in the build settings that don't need to be there